# Should Every Stored Procedure Have an Exception Block?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, exception

I have a client who runs an Oracle 11 database.  The DBA for this client insists that every stored procedure added to the database contain an exception handler (even if the sproc just does a SELECT).  Does this make any sense?  Our data layer on the web site already has built-in exception handling and logging (which works well).  The data layer is written in .NET.

I have told the DBA that an exception handler is only called for when there is some specific action that can be taken in case of an error (like a transaction rollback), or when some predictable error is likely to occur.

He insists that every sproc have an exception block.

Any opinions on whether this is a good or needed practice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Exception handler is not required for every single stored procedure. Some DBAs are stubborn about such things perhaps because they have been bit by rogue procs. I recommend going with his flow and gain his/her trust through meticulous development; help him/her change the belief over a period of time.

Comment: Possibly related:  (it's similar, although there ARE differences in this thread .. ):   https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1270688200346183091

Comment: also:   http://tkyte.blogspot.ca/2008/01/why-do-people-do-this.html

Comment: What does the DBA want the exception handler to do?  I'd be perfectly happy, for example, to add an exception handler that logs the exception, assuming the DBA already has a logging framework in place, and then rethrows the exception.  The DBA may reasonably want to know when procedures are failing.  I'd fight very hard against an exception handler that swallows all exceptions since that tends to make tracking down issues nearly impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to any Oracle-specific need that this may be satisfying.  Maybe there's something the DBA knows that we don't?

But, in general, you're correct.  An exception handler is needed only where one can *meaningfully handle* an exception.  If there's nothing that can be logically done at that point in the code, then there's no reason to catch an exception.  (I wonder... would the DBA's requirement be satisfied if the exception handling block did nothing but re-throw?)

Now, having said that, there's also a certain amount of prudence is following the coding standards set forth by the team which owns a particular system.  That is... Is this a fight worth having?  (In my own *personal* and *not universally applicable* experience, this is a particularly grueling fight with DBAs.  *Especially* DBAs in charge of dinosaurs like Oracle or DB2.  But take that with a grain of salt.)

A good compromise in a situation like this would likely be to sit down with the DBA and discuss what he/she expects the exception handler to *do*.  Logically determine, collaboratively, how to meaningfully handle exceptions in this particular stored procedure.  The DBA may see that there's less need for it, or conversely you may find a need for it that you hadn't considered.  Either way, it's a good opportunity to arrive at an understanding of an otherwise coarsely-expressed blanket rule as it applies to a specific scenario.

Comment: David,  your point is well-taken; I am not sure the fight is worth it.  My main objections to the DBA’s mandate are these:  1.) it adds meaningless code to the sproc in most cases and 2.) it increases the chance that an exception will get “swallowed” instead of bubbling up to the data layer, where it can be logged.  (Obviously, this swallowing would only happen if the developer writing the sproc forgets to re-throw the exception).   Also, it just seems to me that this “every stored procedure must have an exception” block is just mindless (as you say, a “dinosaur” mentality).

Comment: David, P.S... I will take your advice and start a dialogue with him to see if really does have a reason for this rule.  If not, I will try to disabuse him of it.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Ash8087: As with any such struggle in this industry (and I'm sure many, if not all, others), it's important to recognize the possibility that there isn't a technical answer because it may not be a technical problem.  If, regardless of conversation and collaboration on the matter, the bottom line is one of, "It's my DB and I'm in charge and this is my rule," then that's a different problem.  Professionally one can find a lot more reward in being able to discern between technical barriers and political ones.  The latter are rarely worth the struggle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar argument as when to use a checked exception vs. an unchecked exception in Java.  It can be a matter of opinion, but it seems to me that a good starting point is what you have already said:  catch the exception if there's a way you can deal with it.